# Product and limit of many (>2) matrices

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

So I have a matrix like this

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1+iA & iAe^{-2ian/N} \\
-iAe^{2ian/N} & 1-iA
\end{bmatrix} $$

in mathematica form is like this

```
{{1 + I*A, (I*A)/E^(2*I*(na/N))}, {-(I*(A*E^(2*I*(na/N)))), 1 - I*A}}
```

I want to multiply these matrices from n=1 to n=N, for example if I choose N=2 I would have

```
{{1 + I*A, (I*A)/E^(2*I*(a/2))}, {-(I*(A*E^(2*I*(a/2)))), 1 - I*A}} . {{1 + I*A, (I*A)/E^(2*I*(2a/2))}, {-(I*(A*E^(2*I*(2a/2)))), 1 - I*A}}
```

Notice I put "." not "* * " because I want matrix product not some other thing.

After this accomplished I also would like to take the limit of this as well taking N to $\infty$ for example. So I would have something like this, call above matrix $A_{n,N}$
$$ \prod_{n=1}^{N}A_{n,N} $$
where product is of course matrix product.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Check documentation for `MatrixPower`.

Comment: `na/N` watch out `N` is a builtin - use lowercase `n` or another letter (not D, C, E, I, K, O)

Comment: `Dot @@ Table[MA[n,nmax], {n,nmax}]` could get you the finite product, but I'm not sure about taking the limit to infinity...

Comment: @thorimur: Unfortunately, `Dot @@ Table[{{1 + I*A, (I*A)/
     E^(2*I*(n*a/nmax))}, {-(I*(A*E^(2*I*(n*a/nmax)))), 1 - I*A}}, {n,
    1, nmax}]` doen't work. It is useful to chek suggestions.

Comment: @user64494 it does work, for specified `nmax`. have you not given `nmax` a value?

Comment: `Limit[Product[MatrixPower[mat[i], n], {i, n}], n -> Infinity]`  gives: `{{ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate}, {Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity}}`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I would like to say that determinant of this matrix $\prod A_{n,N}$ is 1 for all N. I don't know is there a theorem for such things that guarantees limit exists. Maybe entries of the matrix goes to infinity while keeping determinant 1.